# Recurrance with ceiling

Tags: recurrence-relations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have a problem . 
The exercise says:

> Show that the recurrence $$\begin{align*}&X_0=m\;,\\&X_n=X_{n-1}^2-2\;,\qquad\text{for }n>2\;,\end{align*}$$ has a solution $X_n=\left\lceil\alpha^{2^n}\right\rceil$, if $m$ is an integer greater than $2$, where $\alpha+\alpha^{-1}=m$ and $\alpha>1$. For example, if $m = 3$ the solution is $$X_n=\left\lceil\varphi^{2^{n+1}}\right\rceil\;,\qquad\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\;,\qquad\alpha=\varphi^2\;.$$

Well I have found that

$$\begin{align*}
&X_1=m^2-2\\
&X_2=(m^2-2)^2-2\\
&X_3=\left((m^2-2)^2-2\right)^2-2\\
&\;\vdots
\end{align*}$$

THEN

$$\begin{align*}
\alpha+\alpha^{-1}&=m\iff \alpha^2+\alpha^{-2}+2=m^2\iff \alpha^2+\alpha^{-2}=X_1\\
\left(\alpha^2+\alpha^{-2}\right)^2&=X_1^2\iff X_2=\alpha^4+\alpha^{-4}\\
&\;\;\vdots
\end{align*}$$

I guess that $X_n=\alpha^{2^n}+\alpha^{-2^n}$, where $\alpha>1$ and $n>0$. That clearly holds for $n=0,1,2$.

Let’s say that it holds for $n$ and it must 
hold for $n+1$. By induction we see that

$$X_{n+1}=X_n^2-2=\alpha^{2^{n+1}}+\alpha^{-2^{n+1}}+2-2=\alpha^{2^{n+1}}+\alpha^{-2^{n+1}}$$

Now how do I prove that $X_n$ is an integer (which it must be) and what must I do to end in the answer that the exercise asks for?

Comment: Please use mathjax.

Comment: i tried editing but it there are notations wich are not uniquely interpretable. please modify.

Comment: I dont know what mathjax is .where can i find it ?

Comment: @SidiropoulosAndreas: I’ve edited it for you. You’ll find a MathJax tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve shown that $X_n=\alpha^{2^n}+\alpha^{-2^n}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. On the other hand, it’s clear from the definition that $X_n$ is an integer for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so $\alpha^{2^n}+\alpha^{-2^n}$ is an integer for each $n\in\Bbb N$. We’re told that $\alpha>1$, so $0<\alpha^{-1}<1$, and therefore $0<\alpha^{-2^n}<1$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Thus,

$$X_n-1<X_n-\alpha^{-2^n}=\alpha^{2^n}<X_n\;,$$

where $X_n-1$ and $X_n$ are consecutive integers, and it follows immediately that

$$X_n=\left\lceil\alpha^{2^n}\right\rceil\;.$$

Comment: I cannot understand how Xn<Xn−α−2n=α2n<Xn ,why Xn−1 and Xn are consecutive integers and why to use a ceiling and why not a floor function

Comment: @SidiropoulosAndreas: I accidentally left out a $-1$; it may make better sense now. You know that $X_n$ is an integer: $X_0$ is an integer by definition, and the recurrence ensures that if $X_n$ is an integer, so is $X_{n+1}$, so every $X_n$ is an integer. $X_n-1$ is the next smaller integer, so $X_n-1$ and $X_n$ are consecutive integers. $\alpha^{2^n}$ lies between these two integers, so its ceiling is the larger of the two, which is $X_n$.

Comment: ooo now I see.Thank you.

Comment: @SidiropoulosAndreas: You’re welcome.